# Будет ли большое количество колонок замедлять работу с базой данных?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, структуры-данных, хранение-данных

Реализуем на mysql сбор данных с календарей объявлений на сайте недвижимости

Есть предложение 1 сделать базу с большим колличеством объектов и более чем 370 колонками (5 колонок с разными данными и 365 колонок на каждый день года - календарь с Y/N записями на каждый день). Задача собрать бд и как базовый вариант - интерфейс на php который подключается к базе, по id каждой строки выводить информацию из колонок в кадендарь. Будет ли такое большое количество колонок замедлять работу с базой данных?

Альтернативно есть предложение 2 каждый отдельные день вынести в отдельную строку, однако есть подозрение что это сильно усложнит выведении информации, придется какие-то костыли делать.

Пожалуйста подскажите какой по вашему мнению более выгодный вариант.

Comment: Нормальные формы подсказывают что надо хранить `ИД записи | ИД дня | Y\N`

Comment: @Марина Мартыненко, А для чего такая структура необходима? Почему нельзя записывать в одну колонку дату, а во вторую объявление.

Answer (score 2):

Большое количество колонок может привести к целому ряду проблем:

- Некоторые из ваших запросов могут оказаться крайне медленными;
- Потенциально, информация будет храниться неэффективно;
- Вы теряете в гибкости получения данных и некоторые задачи окажутся не по зубам уже в обозримом будущем;
- Если вам понадобятся индексы на большое число колонок - это приведёт к полному коллапсу.

Для эффективной работы в реляционной СУБД (MySQL) схему ваших таблиц сначала нужно нормализовать.

Пожалуйста, расскажите подробно: а что вы собираетесь хранить 365 в столбцах, отвечающих за дни?

Из описания задачи и схемы таблицы похоже, что вы собираетесь хранить там статистику или похожие на статистику данные. А прямо сейчас вы изобретаете колоночную СУБД (это такие специальные базы для хранения статистически-подобных данных). Если я угадал, рекомендую вам заменить MySQL на ClickHouse (одна из самых известных сегодня колоночных баз): сильно выиграете и в производительности и в простоте разработки.

Comment: Под "заменить" я подразумеваю, что в ClickHouse нужно хранить статистику. Прочие данные можно свободно продолжать хранить в MySQL.